# Telethon: Клиент перехватывает события UserUpdate() не от всех аккаунтов

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

Клиент не перехватывает события *UserUpdate()* для некоторых пользователей.

```
@client.on(events.UserUpdate())
async def normal_handler(event):
# For some users, events are not caught here (online status)
...
```

Что я узнал:

- Эти пользователи есть в адресной книге моего клиента (аккаунта).
- Я могу получить идентификатор, используя как номер телефона, так и имя пользователя.
- С разных аккаунтов все одинаково
- Даже в мобильных и настольных приложениях онлайн-статус этих пользователей не обновляется, пока вы не закроете/откроете чат. Тоесть, при открытом чате время последнего пребывания в сети постоянно увеличиваеться, хотя пользователь уже заходил в сеть. И если обновить чат то время меняеться.

Возможно это не проблема **telethon**, проблема где-то выше.
Есть предположение, что с ID что-то не так. Возможно, причина в удалении пользователя и повторной регистрации.
Или в каких-то настройках пользователя.

Есть ли у вас какие-либо идеи?

[GitHub telethon](https://github.com/LonamiWebs/Telethon)